# How to specify redirect uri using spring social google signin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-social-google

I am using spring social google sign in to login to my spring mvc based web application.

When I try to signin using google I get following error.

```
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:8080/gen/auth/google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 

Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/1014044541-l70us8boluo4a.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=1011 to update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

I have added the redirect uri in google console developer. It is different from what is getting passed in while signing using google.

I have given url as http://localhost:8080/gen/home in google console but it tries to go to http://localhost:8080/gen/auth/google, which is not there in google dev console. It's a mismatch here.

So, how and where do I need to specify the redirect uri in the application?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind the following considerations:

1. According to the oauth2 protocol your server must be able to receive a query from internet

[image]

So you must to provide a reacheable host, not localhost. Try something like dyndns domain (e.g. custom.dyndns.org) and change all the network stuff to allow the incoming traffic to your host specific port

2. In this [link](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/09/02/adding-social-login-to-a-website-using-spring-social/) you will find that if you configure the **SocialAuthenticationFilterCheck** "*it will listen to URL’s that start with /auth and route incoming requests to the corresponding social network provider. E.g. a request sent to /auth/facebook will be redirected to the Facebook provider*"
3. Finally you will have a reachable endpoint like http://custom.dyndns.org:8080/gen and then your 'redirect_uri' must be http://custom.dyndns.org:8080/gen/auth/google